# Database tables clarification

Tags: mysql, database

My friend and I are in the process of creating a database for a take-away assignment, and I'm asking for clarification on the data types and if there is anything that's missing that stands out. We only have to make the following three tables `Food`, `Allergins`, `Delivery/Collection/Price & Availability`. So far, I have the following:

`Food: FoodID (PK), DeliveryID (FK), Description varchar(130), Dish varchar (30), Ingredients varchar(130)`

`Allergins: AllerginsID (PK), FoodID (FK)`

`Delivery/Collection/Price & Availability: DeliveryID (PK), FoodID (FK), Price money, Delivery time, Availability int(2)`

I am aware of formatting, and this isn't the way that I'm going to impliment the program. I'm wondering if the data types I've used are correct, and if there's anything that could be improved.

**EDIT**

I've taken your suggestions on board and tried my best at Normalization, is this any better?

```
Food:
    FoodID          -> PK
    IngredientsID   -> FK
    DeliveryID      -> FK
    Description     -> varchar(130)
    Dish            -> varchar(30)

Allergens:
    AllergensID     -> PK
    FoodID          -> FK
    IngredientsID   -> FK

Delivery & Collection/Price & Availability:
    DeliveryID      -> PK
    FoodID          -> FK
    Price           -> money
    DelTime         -> time
    Availability    -> INT (2)

Ingredients:
    IngredientsID   -> PK
    FoodID          -> FK
    Name            -> varchar (20)

Sizes:
    SizesID         -> PK
    FoodID          -> FK
    Name            -> varchar (2)
```

Comment: It's spelt "allergens".

Comment: (and implement)

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou Sorry! I'm a little bit dyslexic,I'll definitely change that in my program, thanks

Comment: Since we have no idea what this is attempting to store it is challenging to know what improvements could be made. It does appear there are some normalization issues. You have a single column named Ingredients. Since most foods contain more than 1 this should probably be another table. And no idea what the Delivery....table is supposed to represent.

Comment: There's really too much to comment on here. Sorry, but you really need to look again at normalisation.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I'll definitely look into what you have all said :)

Comment: @Strawberry and

Comment: @SeanLange I've made some alterations and attempted normalization, does the edit look any better?

Comment: google 'mysql recipe ingredient'

Comment: Thanks @Strawberry :)

Comment: Not really....there are still several normalization issues. Why is there a deliveryID in the Food table? And the way you have Food and Ingredient it is basically now a 1:1 which is not going to work.